# C# - Wait until the timer's first tick (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, timer, wait

I am creating an application that when you click a button, it waits 10 seconds and executes a certain keystroke via SendKeys. The problem is - it needs to let user move his mouse pointer thorough the windows (ex. select a text box in web browser). So, when i try

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

It isn't working for me, because it frozes the whole GUI and user can't do anything easily.
So, there comes TIMER. I need to set it up (let's call it timer1) to let user wait 10 seconds, enable timer2 with keystroke combination every few seconds and disable timer1 (itself). All without freezing the GUI. When i set timer interval in visual studio, it seems to completely ignore, it doesn't even activate right away, but after +- 50 miliseconds.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: One word for you: Threads http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you doing in web or windows forms?

Comment: Have you tried making a timer and subscribing to its event? Surely if you start a timer correctly it should work? Post how you've tried to make the timer and maybe we can see why its not working as expected

Comment: share your coding ..for better understand what you having ????????

Comment: Yes, i am using Windows Forms.

Comment: Tag your question with what version of .NET or C# you are using.  If .NET 4 then you could use Asynchronous Tasks.  If .NET 4.5 then you could use the same but with the await / async syntax, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Task continuation* in buttonClick event

```
Task.Delay(10000)
    .ContinueWith(_ => YourMethod(), 
               TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

or

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     await Task.Delay(10000);
     YourMethod();
}
```